# Loading a Partial View in MVC ASP.Net using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm very new to both of these so please forgive my basic question.

I have an index page like:

```
<div id="SearchBar">              
    <%= Html.Encode("Search by Site Name: ") + Html.TextBox("SearchTextBox") %>    
    <input type="submit" value="Search" id="jQuerySubmit" />   
</div>
<div id="SiteList">   
    <% Html.RenderPartial("SiteIndexSearchResults", Model); %>                     
</div>
```

This all works fine.

I want to reload this partial based on what the user types in 'SearchTextBox' (I've hardcoded this in controller for now - for test purposes)

I can't get the partial to reload using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#jQuerySubmit").click(function() {
        $("#SiteList").load("/Site/IndexSearch/");         
    });
});
```

It goes into the controller and does return the new view based on IsAjaxResult being true but does not refresh the page.

Thanks in advance.

Davy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers - both really helpful.  I was returning a View instead of a PartialView in my controller (donkey).

I now have a textBox tha incrementally returns rows to my partial list based on a textbox val, which is what i was going for all along.

Thanks Again.

Davy

Answer (score 2):

Since #jQuerySubmit is a form submit button you need to prevent the default action which is submitting the form normally (without AJAX). To do this you need to `return false` from your click handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#jQuerySubmit").click(function() {
        $("#SiteList").load("/Site/IndexSearch/");         
        return false;
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks guys - still not working and tried both approaches in IE and firefox.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You need to stop the "normal" handling of the link click. In most browsers, this is done by letting the click handler return `false`, but in Firefox you can also use [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault), like this:

```
$(function() { // Shorthand for the $(document).ready(function() { - does the same
    $('#jQuerySubmit').click(function(ev) { // Takes the event as a parameter
        ev.preventDefault();
        $('#siteList').load('/Site/IndexSearch/');
        return false;
    });
});
```

If there is a possibility that more links will be loaded with AJAX that you want to apply this behavior to, you can use `.live()` instead of `.click()`, like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#jQuerySubmit').live('click', function(ev) {
        // The behavior is now applied to all links that are ever loaded on the page
        // that have the id set to jQuerySubmit.
        ...
    });
});
```